# Camel..using xpath to parse xml in message body

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jms, apache-camel

I have a simple flow that reads from an activemq1 and parses an id from the message and sends the id across to another activemq2.

Here is an example of message that gets written to activemq1:

```
<Customer>
  <Order>
     <id>123</id>
  </Order>
<Customer>
```

I need to parse out the id from the above message body and send the below message to activemq2:

```
"Order with id{123} has been queued"
```

This is the flow that I cameup with, but it writes the complete request xml to the queue, but not the message that I am looking for:

```
<from uri="jms:queue:Q.activemq1"/>
   <setBody>
        <xpath>"/Customer/Order/id/@value/text()"</xpath>
    </setBody>
 <to uri="jms:queue:Q.activemq2"/>
```

Anything wrong in the above or any corrections

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
<route>
    <from uri="jms:queue:Q.activemq1" />
    <setBody>
        <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">/Customer/Order/id/text()</xpath>
    </setBody>
    <setBody>
        <simple>Order with ${body} has been queued</simple>
    </setBody>
    <log message="${body}"/>
</route>
```

This prints

```
Order with 123 has been queued
```

Comment: Hello, The intention is to send the message(Order with 123 has been queued) accross to activemq2. So, how to concatenate {123} with the rest of the message.

Comment: A good solution. However, I would suggested to use `string()` instead of `text()`, which is better in almost all cases (e.g. if you use `text() you might get back comments in your XML as result, which is almost never intended)

Comment: seems like xpath is not being applied at all. I get the complete xml being transfered <Customer>
  <Order>
     <id>123</id>
  </Order>
<Customer>

Comment: This is the error..looks like it is treating it as a dob object instead of a string/text   caught: org.apache.camel.builder.xml.InvalidXPathExpression: Invalid xpath: /Customer/Order/id/text(). Reason: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Comment: I erred...This is the exact error that iam seeing...Using converter: InstanceMethodTypeConverter: public java.lang.String org.apache.camel.converter.jaxp.DomConverter.toString(org.w3c.dom.NodeList,org.apache.camel.Exchange) throws javax.xml.transform.TransformerException to convert [class org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList=>class java.lang.String]

Comment: @user1717230 Your XML is not valid, it misses a slash: it should end with `</Customer>` and not with `<Customer>`.

Comment: Was not working with text() or string(). This worked finally.<xpath resultType="java.lang.String">/Customer/Order/id</xpath>

Comment: I added `resultType` to my solution but kept `text()` in order to signalize that the node *content* is read